Send Message to IBM MQ (PUT) with SSL from Java takes a long time to complete
The following Java program is used to send a message to MQ 9.3.5 (Windows Based). It works fine and takes less than a second to complete if not using SSL. When using SSL, it takes about 80 seconds to complete and this indicates a problem.
When connecting the MQ on Linux, the send message operation takes less than a second for both SSL and non-SSL connections.
Any idea how to troubleshoot this issue?
import com.ibm.mq.MQC;
import com.ibm.mq.MQException;
import com.ibm.mq.MQGetMessageOptions;
import com.ibm.mq.MQMessage;
import com.ibm.mq.MQPutMessageOptions;
import com.ibm.mq.MQQueue;
import com.ibm.mq.MQQueueManager;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Hashtable;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;


@SuppressWarnings({ "rawtypes", "unchecked","deprecation" })

public class TestIBMMQ {

    static String theQueueMgr;
    static String theRequestQueue;
    static String respQueue;
    static String mesgId = null;
    static String corrId = null;
    static MQQueue objQueue = null;
    static String replyQueue;
    static String replyQmgr;

    static boolean isSSLActive;


    public TestIBMMQ() {

    }

    public static ResourceBundle getProperties(String file) {
        ResourceBundle resourceBundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle(file);
        return resourceBundle;
    }

    public static String getFileContent(String path) {
        StringBuffer stringbuffer = null;
        try {
            File file = new File(path);

            FileReader filereader = new FileReader(file);
            BufferedReader bufferedreader = new BufferedReader(filereader);
            stringbuffer = new StringBuffer();
            String s = System.getProperty("line.separator");
            String s1;
            while ((s1 = bufferedreader.readLine()) != null) {
                stringbuffer.append(s1);
                stringbuffer.append(s);
            }
            filereader.close();
            bufferedreader.close();
        } catch (IOException ioexception) {
            ioexception.printStackTrace();
        }
        return stringbuffer.toString();
    }

    public static void sendMessage(String msgText, MQQueueManager qMgr, boolean isResponse) {
        try {

            String theQueueMgr = <fetch Queue Manager Name>;
            String theRequestQueue = <fetch Request Queue Name>;

            if (theRequestQueue != null && theRequestQueue.length() > 0) {

                objQueue = qMgr.accessQueue(theRequestQueue, MQC.MQOO_OUTPUT, null, null, null);

            } else {
                System.out.println("Request Queue (request_queue) was not configured! Tool now tries to get any response..");
            }

            MQMessage mqmessage = new MQMessage();

            if (resBund.getString("message_expiry") != null && resBund.getString("message_expiry").length() > 0) {
                mqmessage.expiry = Integer.valueOf(resBund.getString("message_expiry"));
            }

            // The default value is MQC.MQEI_UNLIMITED (-1), which means that
            // the message never expires.
            System.out.println("Message expiry set to ... " + mqmessage.expiry);

            if (!mesgId.equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
                mqmessage.messageId = mesgId.getBytes();
                // mqmessage.correlationId = mesgId.getBytes();
            } else {
                mqmessage.messageId = MQC.MQMI_NONE;
            }

            if (!corrId.equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
                mqmessage.correlationId = corrId.getBytes();
            } else {
                mqmessage.correlationId = MQC.MQCI_NONE;
            }

            mqmessage.writeString(msgText);

            if (!isResponse) {
                mqmessage.replyTotheQueueMgrName = resBund.getString("replyToQmgr");
                mqmessage.replyToQueueName = resBund.getString("replyToQueue");
            }

            MQPutMessageOptions mqputmessageoptions = new MQPutMessageOptions();
            objQueue.put(mqmessage, mqputmessageoptions);

            System.out.println("Message successfully PUT... ");
        } catch (MQException mqexception) {
            System.out.println("An MQSeries error occurred : Completion code " + mqexception.completionCode + " Reason code " + mqexception.reasonCode);
            System.out.println(mqexception.getCause());
        } catch (IOException ioexception1) {
            System.out.println("An error occurred whilst writing to the message buffer: " + ioexception1);
            ioexception1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception exception) {
            System.out.println("An error occurred : " + exception.getMessage());
            exception.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                if (objQueue != null)
                    objQueue.close();
                // qMgr.disconnect();
            } catch (MQException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ATSException {

        String prop;
        if (args.length > 0) {
            prop = args[0];
        } else {
            prop = "<some properties file...";
        }

        resBund = getProperties(prop);

        // MQ Objects
        theQueueMgr = resBund.getString("queue_manager");
        theRequestQueue = resBund.getString("request_queue");
        respQueue = resBund.getString("response_queue");
        mesgId = resBund.getString("mesg_id");
        corrId = resBund.getString("corrID");

        MQQueueManager qMgr = null;

        Hashtable mqProperties = new Hashtable();
        mqProperties.put(MQC.HOST_NAME_PROPERTY, resBund.getString("host"));
        mqProperties.put(MQC.CHANNEL_PROPERTY, resBund.getString("channel"));
        mqProperties.put(MQC.PORT_PROPERTY, Integer.parseInt(resBund.getString("port")));
        mqProperties.put(MQC.TRANSPORT_PROPERTY, MQC.TRANSPORT_MQSERIES);
        
        if (resBund.getString("ssl_active") != null && resBund.getString("ssl_active").equalsIgnoreCase("y")) {
            isSSLActive = true;
            System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", resBund.getString("sslmq.trust.store"));
            System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", resBund.getString("sslmq.key.store"));
            System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword", ATSPasswordEncoder.decode(resBund.getString("mqssl.keystore.pwd")));
        }
        

        try {

            File targDir = new File(resBund.getString("msg_file_path"));

            if (!isSSLActive) {
                qMgr = new MQQueueManager(theQueueMgr, mqProperties);
            } else {
                mqProperties.put(MQC.SSL_CIPHER_SUITE_PROPERTY, resBund.getString("sslmq.cipher.suite"));
                qMgr = new MQQueueManager(theQueueMgr, mqProperties);
            }

            if (resBund.getString("send_req") != null && resBund.getString("send_req").equalsIgnoreCase("y")) {
                if (targDir.isDirectory()) {
                    for (File file : targDir.listFiles()) {
                        if (theRequestQueue != null && theRequestQueue.length() > 0) {
                            System.out.println(file.getName() + " is being sent to Queue ..... " + theRequestQueue);
                            sendMessage(getFileContent(file.getAbsolutePath()), qMgr, false);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            if (qMgr != null) {
                qMgr.disconnect();
                qMgr = null;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (qMgr != null) {
                try {
                    qMgr.disconnect();
                } catch (MQException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                qMgr = null;
            }
        }
    }// main ends

}

Note: The above program was simplified before it is included here. I confirm it works 100% correctly but the above version may have errors and it is to showcase the approach.

Confirming that connecting to a queue manager running on windows takes 80 seconds but connecting to a queue manager running on Linux takes less than 1 second?  Have you compared the qm.ini "SSL:" stanza to see if Linux and windows are configured the same?  OCSP checks can cause similar behavior depending on the configuration.

If you issue DISPLAY CHSTATUS(svrconn-chl-name) on the queue manager while these 80 seconds are passing, what value do you see reported in the SUBSTATE attribute of the response to that command?

@JoshMc so I can disable OCSP checks but what does that mean? Is it a bad thing?

My thought was to check if it was disabled on Linux and not on windows.  Disabling  it would mean the queue manager will not check OCSP  to see if the remote certificate is revoked.

Hi takekahf - to see what the network connected app is doing, assuming that it is taking a long time to do one thing, the CHSTATUS SUBSTATE attribute can help hugely. If it is OCSP as @JoshMc suggests you would see SUBSTATUS(SSLHANDSK). Alternatively you could put some logging in your application to print out things like "About to connect", "Finished the connect", "About to Put a message", "Finished putting a message" and so on, to see exactly where the 80 seconds were spent. You could even add timing in the output from your application if it wasn't clear.
